# Generate table from entities jpa/hibernate with eclipselink orm

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink, entities

I'm trying to generate tables from entities using , jpa2.0 hibernate 4.2.16 and I got this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/EntityNotFoundDelegate
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.EntityNotFoundDelegate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more`

My librairies contain : 
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar and hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.16.Final.jar

Comment: using which implementation? Hibernate? so what has EclipseLink got to do with the problem?

Comment: In the Jpa propreties if I put the platform on the top in generic 2.0 rather that Eclipselink2.1 I got this message when I try to generate table from entities using the jpa tools "DLL generation is not supported by the generic plateforme " I need help I'm new comer to Java EE word

Comment: I figured out either I use EclipseLink or Hibernate not the two of them. it's Ok I found the solution.